# 8086 emulator. Issue with i8086 istallation

Tags: software-recommendation, 13.04, emulation

I am an emu8086 user, and I find it very good, but it exists only in windows.
Are there any good ubuntu 8086 emulator?

I need it to practice 16bit assembly code.
I care about seeing what happens on the registers, at every instruction execution.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine under wine.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```